# Desktop switch acts as gateway

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, switch

I have a network switch that's used to share my internet at home.The router is connected to the switch and several other devices are connected to the various switch ports in different rooms.Everything works as desired until there is a power outage. Once the power is back, the switch loads up before the router and hence all devices connected to it thinks it's the gateway and assigns switch IP as gateway there by losing internet connectivity.

The workaround is to manually turn off the switch and wait until the router is up and then turn switch back on which is a hassle. I ended up assigning static IP address to my PC so it still recognizes the correct gateway(router). But I have other streaming devices like Roku, TV and so on connected to the switch that can't be assigned static IP addresses.

How do I resolve this issue? Why does the devices think my switch is the gateway even after the router comes back online? It's an unmanaged switch so I cant configure it either.

Comment: What kind of switch do you have? A typical home  layer 2 switch does not have any IP address except possibly for management. Sounds like it might have a built-in DHCP server enabled and that is your issue?

Comment: @EddieDunn - this is the switch    https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B000FNFSPY/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: How did you determine that the IP address that shows up as the 'gateway' actually belongs to the switch?

Comment: @grawity has a good point. It could just not be getting an address from and using APIPA. Does the address that you get when it breaks start with 169 by chance?

Comment: My suspicion is more that it isn't the switch, but another computer/device connected to the same switch, that runs an unwanted DHCP server...

Comment: @grawity - I looked up all connected devices from the router admin page and found out the IP address belongs to the switch. Confirmed it by removing it from the network and the address disappeared from the router admin list.

Comment: @grawity - now thinking about it, I have a wifi extender connected to the switch as well. Could that be the culprit? will it act as dhcp server? --https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00R92CL5E/ref=oh_aui_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1